# In C++ what's the easiest way for a user to enter data going into a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, user-interface, user-input

I want the program to take user input to fill a 2D array of `int`s and I'm not sure what the easiest format to have the user enter the data would be (easy in terms of programming).

For example in Java I could use `.split()` to separate integers by spaces or commas etc., but since a string can't easily be broken up in C++, this is a problem.

I don't want to prompt the user each time for each element such as:

```
enter integer for location 0, 0
enter integer for location 0,10
enter integer for location 2, 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Java has a `spit()` method? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stackoverflow answer that talks about how to tokenize a string in C++

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

I haven't tried boost but strtok is pretty easy to use but may have some multithreading issues.